# How to fetch/extract shareable posts using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph.facebook.com/posts to fetch the profile posts of a user and trying to extract the posts that are shareable. Is there a field in the Post or some condition which suggests that the post is shareable by others?

Comment: I figured out that, if the post contains a link/photo/video etc, the post will be shareable by default. If the post is a status update and it has a link it is shareable. posts with links will have the type 'link'. 

If the post doesn't contain a link, then it is shareable if it is public. Are there any other logic in addition to this?